# To 'forward' BizTalk BAM events to cloud

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam

Think about a scenario to migrate BizTalk BAM events to a cloud log saas provider, e.g. a provider data collection via HTTP post calls. How to achieve this with minimum pain, ideally to 'intercept' a BAM API call so the existing spreadsheet defined activities could somehow reused without replace the tracking all over with custom coding. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to accomplish exactly what you describe.  However...

The intended way to get the effect of what you're describing is to build this telemetry into your app using Application Insights as the target.